# How to use transient attributes in Fabrication's count parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fabrication-gem

I have this fabricator for a Rails model:

```
Fabricator(:foo) do
  transient n_iterations: 5

  bar(count: :n_iterations) { Fabricate(:bar) }
end
```

However, this doesn't work as hoped. I've tried `count: n_iterations`, `count: attrs[:n_iterations]`, and `count: attrs[n_iterations]`, and nothing seems to work. This seems like it should be a relatively simple thing to do though.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
Fabricator(:foo) do
  transient n_iterations: 5
  bar { |attrs| (1..attrs[:n_iterations]).map { Fabricate(:bar) } }
end
```

Note, however, that `Fabricate(:foo, n_iterations: 0)` will return a `Foo` with `bar => []` an empty array.